# Defining layout_weight as horizontal?

Tags: android

I am trying to use android:layout_weight but I can't. I use linearlayout and I use vertical orientation because when I use horizontal every element goes on one line.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
     >
```

When I use vertical android assign weight az vertically.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etFirstNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
         />

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSecondNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
         />
```

Look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7mXI.jpg)(sorry I haven't enough reputation).

The thing that I want to do is putting two edittext elements on same line. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
     <TextView 
     ....
     ...
     ..
     </TextView>

     <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etFirstNumber"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5" />

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSecondNumber"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"/>
     </LinearLayout>
     <Button 
     ....
     ...
     ..
     </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

for Horizontal Layout `use android:orientation="horizontal"` in you `LinearLayout` with :

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

for Vertical Layout `use android:orientation="vertical"` in you `LinearLayout` with :

```
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

change the layout orientation to `Horizontal`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the EditText(s) in a new LinearLayout to manage the hierarchy better. Also set the width as 0dp so the `layout_weight` works correctly.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etFirstNumber"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5" />

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etSecondNumber"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```